# How to get schema of input in exec function in Pig UDF

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I wonder how I can get get schema of input in exec() function when I build UDF in Piglatin. I can get schema from outputSchema() function but looks like the result can't be leveraged by backend functions.

Any hints will be highly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a getInputSchema method in Pig's UDF (EvalFunc). Have you tried it?

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html